# Custom trigger for length of TextBox text

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

In the trigger below, if `TextBox` `Text` value is empty, `Border` color will be Red.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" > 
    <Style.Triggers> 
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">      
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/> 
        </Trigger> 
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How can I (with trigger) do that when the length on the text is under 4 chars the border will be red?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think what you want to do is data validation. WPF has some tools for that - have a look at [http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)

Comment: If you definitively want to do that with style trigger, you'd have to write your own converter.

Comment: You can check if Text Length is say 4 exact, then Color could be Red. But for less than , greater than scenarios you have to use behaviors.

Comment: @jHilscher
can you please show me how to write the convertor?
i want do the condition on trigger
if i will use on convertor it will be greate!

Comment: @jordan I answered the question with a converter example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a Style.Trigger based solution you need a converter:

The converter converts the String input to a Boolean, weather the input meets your criteria. In this example the text length must be bigger than 4.

Converter Class:

```
public class LengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var text = value as string;

        if (text != null) {
            return text.Length > 4;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:LengthConverter x:Key="converter" />
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Converter={StaticResource converter}}"
                    Value="False">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

But a proper validation (like in Szabolcs Dézsi's answer) is probably the better approach.

Comment: thanks!
can you explain why did you done "StaticResource converter" ?

Comment: this is just a reference to <conv:LengthConverter x:Key="converter" /> which references the LengthConverter

Comment: Just wanted to add that you need to define "conv" for this to work. Add "xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE" to your window definition.

Comment: Also, your converter is testing to see if the value is an int and whether that int is greater than 4, which is not what the question asked for. The converter should be testing if the input value's length is under 4 chars. Replace the contents of the Convert() with simply this: "return value.ToString().Length < 4" and also flip your DataTrigger Value to "True"

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you want to implement some kind of validation.

Instead of using a trigger I would use the built in validation features of WPF.

One way of doing this is to implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your view model (or model).

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
```

`Error` property implementation:

```
public string Error { get { return null; } }
```

The indexer's implementation:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if(columnName == "SomeRandomText")
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(SomeRandomText) || SomeRandomText.Length < 4)
            {
                return "Text should be at least four characters long";
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeRandomText, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Result:

[image: Result]

If you don't want to implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface you can use `ValidationRule`s.

Same thing achieved with a `ValidationRule`:

```
<Binding Path="SomeRandomText" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
    <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:LengthValidationRule RequiredLength="4" />
    </Binding.ValidationRules>
</Binding>
```

And the `ValidationRule`:

```
public class LengthValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public int RequiredLength { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var text = (string)value;

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) || text.Length < RequiredLength)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Text should be at least four characters long");
        }

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

If you want to have a different border you can look into the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property.

If you really want to do this with a trigger, as others mentioned you can do it with a converter named for example `LessThanConverter`. It would take the `Length` of the `Text` and the other number you want to compare it with as the `ConverterParameter` and would return a `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Reference assemblies : 
`Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll`, and 
`System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` .
On my machine they are in : 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries`

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="96,0,0,164.04" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">              
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <ei:ConditionBehavior>
                            <ei:ConditionalExpression>
                                <ei:ComparisonCondition Operator="LessThan" RightOperand="4" LeftOperand="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=textBox}"/>
                            </ei:ConditionalExpression>
                        </ei:ConditionBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="BorderBrush">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFD41717"/>
                        </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
```