# WPF C# change resource dictionary accent color in code

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, resourcedictionary

i have a TextBox [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tj3Ck.gif)
The textbox highlights when selected, & uses the accent color from the resource dictionary in app.xaml

```
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Green.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
```

& if the username is less than 8 characters i'd like the accent color to turn to red, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried. Also, it might be a good idea to use SO to host your images instead of providing some external link. People might not feel comfortable clicking on external links (malware)

Comment: i have tried to make a binding and set a value that changes depending on the length of the textbox, but i'm not too familiar with bindings so im not sure exactly if that would work.

I updated the link to the gif, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to overwrite the template for that textbox locally to add a datatrigger that triggers on a IValueConverter.
Without seeing the template in question i can't really be more specific as we can't know how the accent is set up.
Further reading:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=net-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-apply-template?view=netdesktop-5.0
- [Custom trigger for length of TextBox text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706925/custom-trigger-for-length-of-textbox-text)

Comment: Thank you for the links & advice, i'll try this & let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your explanation is clear on what your question is.. From what I understand you're asking how you would change the color of the text if it's less than 8 characters?
If that's your question then 'string.Length' should suffice.

Comment: its not the text that i'd like to change the color of, if you see the gif i posted it shows what i'd like to recolor, its the line at the bottom, underneath the text. it takes the color from the resource dictionary in app.xaml & i was wondering if i could change that depending on the length of string in the textbox